# Manual Grid View Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

My Grid View is manually data bound (for other things to work). Reading other threads I have to manage my own sorting events.

When clicking a column to sort it on my webpage I get the error:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The result of this was that table was null, but I cannot see why it is null.

Any ideas?

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = GetData();
    table.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SetSortDirection(e.SortDirection.ToString());
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

.

```
protected string SetSortDirection(string currentsortDirection)
{
    string sortDirection;
    if (currentsortDirection == "Ascending")
    {
        sortDirection = "Descending";
    }
    else
    {
        sortDirection = "Ascending";
    }
    return sortDirection;
}
```

EDIT:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE Property='" + Request.QueryString["xxx"] + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return dt;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: kindly debug your application and have a look at the value of `BuildInfo_GridView.DataSource`

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataTable table = BuildInfo_GridView.DataSource as DataTable;
```

like this u won't get the datasource what u already binded call back end query to get tha datatable or when u r binding the data only store it in view state and get it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question, with the current code I can only sort one way, so when I assign the data back it will say e.SortDirection="Ascending" no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Save your sort order in view state
if (ViewState["sortOrder"] != null)
            {
                ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString().ToUpper() == "ASCENDING")
                {
                    e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                    ViewState["sortOrder"] = SortDirection.Descending.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    ViewState["sortOrder"] = SortDirection.Ascending.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                ViewState["sortOrder"] = e.SortDirection.ToString();
            }
```